# What is gained by giving categories an identity arrow?

Tags: category-theory

We give groups their axioms of closure, associativity, inverse, and identity, so we can "do algebra" or equivalently, study symmetries in a very general sense. What new can we do by adding the requirement that a category contain arrows from an object to itself? Surely this removes some level of generality, which I think the idea of creating categories was seeking after?

I know there are many examples of categories, and that this is used to show the importance of them. But I'm sure there's a reason we use categories in each case, and that there must be at least a vague thread that goes through all of them. I'm not so interested in specific applications, if possible but if so that's fine.

QUESTION: by giving category objects unique identity arrows what useful (but AS GENERAL AS POSSIBLE) property is gained? Since I'm not familiar with this part of math I'd appreciate something that's intuive and in layman's terms. :) Thanks.

Comment: Definitions of certain fundamental concepts like $\text{inverse of } f : A \to B$ are defined by saying $f^{-1} \circ f = \text{id}_A$ and $f \circ f^{-1} = \text{id}_B$ . Talking about these things is more awkward if you don't have a notion of an identity arrow.

Comment: It's worth noting that the identity arrow for an object $a$, if it exists, is uniquely definable in terms of composition alone: it's the unique arrow from $a$ to $a$ which is both a left and right identity for composition among arrows from $a$ to $a$. This does in fact pick it out uniquely: if $f,g$ are two such arrows, then $fg=f$ (right-identity-ness of $g$) and $fg=g$ (left-identity-ness of $f$), and so $f=g$.

Comment: More substantively, you write "this removes some level of generality, which I think the idea of creating categories was seeking after" - but generality is not inherently a good thing. For example, groups are much more useful than magmas. The trick is hitting the right (or *a* right) level of generality. Certainly demanding identity arrows rules some things out (e.g. arbitrary magmas can't be thought of as one-element categories), but so does demanding that composition of arrows be associative, or that source and target be unique, or ...

Comment: Also, just because it's not *commonly* done doesn't mean it's ruled out: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semicategory

Comment: @Noah Schweber thanks, that actually makes more sense now. I haven't had time to read the duplicate yet, but after skimming it I realized I'd forgoten to ask about associativity too, since I started typing this question a while ago and forgot what I'd originally had in mind. I may consider reopening this question with that added. Two follow up questions to your response: does every arrow have to be composable of two others, and does the class of non-identity maps need to include one acting on EVERY element of the set?If so I assume this is derivable from the definition of an abstract category?

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn If I understand your questions correctly, the answer is *no* to each. For the first, consider the category $\mathcal{C}$ with two objects $A$ and $B$ and a single nonidentity arrow $f$ going from $A$ to $B$. Then $f$ is not the composition of any two arrows. (Unless you allow the trivial compositions, namely $f=f\circ id_A=id_B\circ f$ - if you allow these, then the answer to your first question is *yes*.) This also gives a weak negative answer to your second question: in $\mathcal{C}$, no nonidentity arrow has target $A$ or source $B$. (cont'd)

Comment: And of course we can do much better: consider e.g. a category with $17$ objects and no non-identity arrows at all. So there's actually very little we're guaranteed to get from the axioms - including the existence of *any* non-identity arrows at all!

Comment: This is one reason existence of id arrows is desirable.  Take __Yoneda's Lemma__: https://enjoysmath.blogspot.com/2022/07/90-visual-proof-of-contravariant-yoneda.html

This lemma is applied in about 30% of the category theory proofs, and by that I mean directly.  The other theorems probably indirectly use it.  So 90% of category theory relies on Yoneda somewhere in the proof tree, and Yoneda definitely needs _something_ there to grab ahold of and map around that triangular prism diagram I drew (see link).